# Grub boot probelm

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows

I have Ubuntu 14.04.2 installed on my first HDD (500GB) with a second drive(1TB) as a backup (500GB), and the rest(500GB) non allocated.

I needed to run a windows based only program for school so installed Windows 8.1 on the 500GB unallocated slot on my backup drive. Windows installation was fine no problems to report.

After initial installation of Windows I wanted to update my grub: `sudo update-grub`, then rebooted to see the changes. Grub listed Ubuntu, and Windows 8 (loader), selected Windows 8 and heard a(1) beep from the internal speaker, the screen is stuck as Purple (#772953). I tried typing but the beep kept going off at every keystroke.

Next I tried:

- boot repair, same thing, no change.
- booted from Windows 8.1 USB and selected startup repair, it failed but the error log was blank.
- Checked the file-system of Windows 8.1, nothing wrong.
- I tried manually selecting the windows HDD for boot but grub is installed on both the drives and same problem persists.

Problem: Windows 8.1 will not boot, startup repair failed: no error was given, boot-repair: no fix.

Bootrepair pastebin [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10616411/)

*How should I proceed?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows always needs to be installed on the first partition of the first drive of the computer...  (and that's what you get from a near-monopoly)

So you need to install Windows first and then Ubuntu.  :-(

Comment: Don't thank me!  ;-) If you like my answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask

Comment: Windows is very "funny"